# Django click input action can create duplicates

Tags: python, django, request, create-view

Both in admin and in custom view, I'm experiencing this:

- add new record
- compile form
- click the save button multiple times as
  fast as possible
- many records with same data have been created

Is this a bug? is this correct?

I think there must be another level of validation to avoid duplicate entries. Should I edit all form class or there is a best, fast way?

Comment: How are you committing your form, via AJAX or is it a regular HTTP POST (no JS involved)?

Comment: I'm seeing this from standard django admin interface v. 1.9.2, simply create a model, register, and add new record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Concerning regular Django views:

You will have to handle this on your own. It is not desirable that Django imposes anything. Consider your view part of a REST service where clients would call the view in an automatic process - throttling would not be desired.

If you need throttling for a REST interface you might want to have a look at Django Rest Framework's Throttling: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

#### Concerning the Django Admin:

There might be styles for the Django Admin that implement throttling on the JS side. Or you add your own JS snippet that throttles the clicks.

Whether this is really necessary - you might want to wait for the staff users to complain.

#### Avoiding Duplicate Entries

Make sure you set `unique=True` and/or `unique_together = ()` (a Meta attribute) on your Models to have your database check before duplicate entries are created.

Comment: Thanks for advices, I've tried the model meta option, this works correctly, but  got error from view django.db.utils.IntegrityError

Comment: Yes, certainly. You will have to either throttle the clicks in your views or handle the error message in your views (probably under the hood). The DB constraint will simply make sure that your data is not corrupted.